# How to my own cmdlet (using C#) with two input parameters mandatory but mutually exclusive?

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

I'm developing PowerShell Cmdlets in C#. I would like to define mandatory parameters, but that are mutually exclusive.

Example:

```
Parameter A
Parameter B
```

When invoking the command, I must set only parameter A or only parameter B, but I cannot set both and I cannot set none.

Comment: Not sure there is any kind of aspect, or modifier which will allow you to enforce this without just doing parameter validation in your cmdlet code. Why not just do that ?